# Database table is locked (C# , Sqlite3)

Tags: c#, sqlite

```
SQLiteCommand sqlite_cmd_show;
SQLiteConnection sqlite_conn;
SQLiteDataReader sqlite_datareader;

sqlite_cmd_show = sqlite_conn.CreateCommand();
sqlite_cmd_show.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM stock WHERE item_barcode = @barcode and serial_data != '' and serial_data > @serial";
sqlite_cmd_show.Parameters.Add("@barcode", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
sqlite_cmd_show.Parameters.Add("@serial", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);

for (int count = 0; count < DataGItem.Rows.Count; count++)
{
    isExist = false;

sqlite_cmd_show.Parameters["@barcode"].Value = (String)DataGItem.Rows[count].Cells[1].Value;
sqlite_cmd_show.Parameters["@serial"].Value = (String)DataGItem.Rows[count].Cells[6].Value;

sqlite_datareader = sqlite_cmd_show.ExecuteReader();
while (sqlite_datareader.Read())
{
    isExist = true;
    break;
}

if (isExist)
{
    continue;
}

sqlite_cmd = sqlite_conn.CreateCommand();
sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "Insert into stock ( stock_id, item_barcode ) VALUES ("+ stock_id +",'" + txtDocNo.Text + "')";
sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This is my example code and Its error at the last line "sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();"

The error is

#### An unhandled exception of type 'Finisar.SQLite.SQLiteException' occurred in SQLite.NET.dll

#### Additional information: database table is locked

So,I tried to do many things but it's not work

Please Help,

Comment: You should close your reader after using it

Comment: I already add  sqlite_datareader.Dispose(); and  sqlite_datareader.Close();  before but it still same.

Comment: you probably should wrap `sqlite_datareader = sqlite_cmd_show.ExecuteReader();` in a `using(...) { ... }` block

Comment: @PhudisSaweangsuk You should update your code with your change. (and fix the missing })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close your connection before the insert statement

```
sqlite_conn.Close()
```

Then open a new one

```
sqlite_conn.Open()
```